# How to change Nodes Size and Edge weight NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx, social-networking

How do I  play with the edge thickness and node size base on the weight?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G_weighted = nx.Graph()
G_weighted.add_edge('abc','lifestyle', weight=5)
G_weighted.add_edge('abc','livestream', weight=3)
G_weighted.add_edge('abc','sony', weight=1)


plt.figure(figsize=(25,18))
nx.draw_networkx(G_weighted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `width` and `node_size` attributes:

```
G_weighted.nodes['abc']['weight'] = 500
G_weighted.nodes['lifestyle']['weight'] = 900
G_weighted.nodes['livestream']['weight'] = 700
G_weighted.nodes['sony']['weight'] = 1100

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

edge_weight = list(nx.get_edge_attributes(G_weighted,'weight').values())
node_weight = list(nx.get_node_attributes(G_weighted,'weight').values())

nx.draw_networkx(G_weighted, width=edge_weight, node_size=node_weight)
```

Node that that large parameters of `figsize` autoscales display of graph to fit the screen so I reduced them in order to keep natural size of nodes and edges.